# Efficient way to send mails

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a class that will handle mails and I am using PHP. I know how to send mail using PHP's native mail function. But i am trying to create an efficient mailing system within a class. I had come up with what all things i need to have in my class.

- Method to verify email address(using regular expressions)
- Method to filter email address(remove all unwanted characters and injected headers and other false data)
- Method to send plain text email
- Method to send html email
- Property to assign to address
- Property to assign from address
- Property to assign subject
- Property to assign body
- Mass mailing method

So how to make it in efficient way. I need ideas on what all things to take care of and other things. To validate email address i had seen a regex pattern that is a big one which is the standard. But if i use that it will be consuming more processing. Correct ?

And I do not want the email address to be considered as spam.
What do you use for the above said things ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might consider using [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), as it has mostly everthing you want and is used in many products and frameworks, so you can be sure it's fairly stable. I use it for some time now, mostly within symfony1 and symfony2, and I think you'll have a hard time creating something similar.

Comment: thank you. Can you please tell me how to send mass mails using swiftmailer ? Like email newsletter or global announcement to all my users

Comment: Please have a look at batch mailing: http://swiftmailer.org/docs/sending.html#sending-emails-in-batch Also have a look at the plugins (e.g. decorator to set username in every email etc.): http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html